# Nominalizer の use

Tags: particles

Thank you for the so useful site you have. I'm studying by my self and I have found answer to a lot of questions I had.
 I'm using Nihongo somatome to try N3 and there is a sentence with の that I don't catch very well:
私は少し苦みのあるコーヒーが好きです。
In fact, is a sentence you have to sort properly, and my answer was:
私は少し苦みあるコーヒーのが好きです。
Why after の there is ある？I thought that always it would follow a particle...
Thank you in advance!

Sandra

Answer (score 3):

Your question isn't entirely clear to me, but I'll try to break down the sentence for you:

> 私は［［少し苦みのある］コーヒー］が好きです。
>   I-TOP [[a little bitterness-OBJ have] coffee]-OBJ like-COP.
>   'I like coffee which has a little bitterness.' (Literal)
>   'I like slightly bitter coffee.'

The の in 苦みのある is actually a が which has undergone GA-NO conversion, which is possible since it's a relative clause.

There is no need for a の after ある because verbs can directly modify nouns.

There is no need for a の before が because ［少し苦みのある］コーヒー is a noun already.

Comment: I see... Now I understand it! I hadn't thought about a missed が... Sorry for the way I wrote my question but English is not my mother tongue, so sometimes I make mistakes.
Thank you for so quickly and clear answer!